# convert string to date format in data-weave ( for json to xml scenario)

Tags: json, xml, date, mule, transformation

I am stuck in a very small issue i am getting date in this below format

```
{
"mydate":"2016-05-12"
}
```

and i want to convert this date in to my format that is **12-MAY-2017** but while doing json to xml transformation,  i am getting error:-**can coerce string to date** below my dw script but this one is not working

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

---
{
    "test":payload.mydate as :string {format:"dd-mm-yyyy"}
}
```

Please advice !!

Cheers,
Bsolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    "test":payload.mydate as :date {format:"yyyy-MM-dd"} as :string {format:"dd-MMM-yyyy"}
}
```

For dataweave Date format schema is based on [Java DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). You were using `mm` it actually denotes minute-of-hour. `MM` or `LL` should be used for month-of-year.

Hope this helps.